# Angular 6: Function call within HTML interpolation returns undefined

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm attempting to call a function inside my HTML interpolation, like so. This HTML chunk is inside a `*ngFor` loop.

```
<mat-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let unit of units">
    <div>
        <p>Remaining Life</p>
        <h2>{{ parseTimeRemaining(unit.daysRemaining) }}</h2>
    </div>
    </mat-list-item>
<mat-list>
```

`parseTimeRemaining()` returns a string to be displayed, using the value of `unit.daysRemaining` as a parameter.

```
public parseTimeRemaining(days: number){
    const timeString = days + " Days";
    return timeString;
}
```

Currently, my function returns `undefined` and thus, an empty `<h2>` element. Did I do something wrong? If so, what's the best way to display the information I need?

Comment: Note that it is not recommended to bind functions to the template for performance reasons since they are called during every change detection cycle. You should bind variables instead.

Comment: Your problem is not in the code you provided.

https://angular-y8tngp.stackblitz.io

Please check how you are setting the data and what else is going on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be a great opportunity to use a Pipe instead of a function. This helps to avoid calling a function within an `*ngFor` which can have detrimental affects to performance. From the documentation surrounding [pipes and change detection](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pipes-and-change-detection).

> Angular picks a simpler, faster change detection algorithm when you
>   use a pipe.

Angular has a built-in pipe, [I18nPluralPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/I18nPluralPipe) which "Maps a value to a string that pluralizes the value according to locale rules.". You create an object (pluralMap) targeting specific numerical values and indicate the resulting string should be allowing to say `0 Days`, `1 Day`, or `99 days`.

```
pluralMap = {
  '=0': '0 Days',
  '=1': '1 Day',
  'other': '# Days'
};
```

You would use it in a template as follows:

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let unit of units">{{ unit.daysRemaining | i18nPlural:pluralMap }}</li>
</ul>
```

Another approach would be to create a [Custom Pipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#custom-pipes). This would allow you implement custom formatting and/or validation logic against the provided `daysRemaining`.

**Pipe:**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'daysRemaining'})
export class DaysRemainingPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(days: number): string {
    const timeString = days + " Days";
    return timeString;
  }
}
```

**Module (registration):**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'; 
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DaysRemainingPipe } from './days-remaining.pipe';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, DaysRemainingPipe ]
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Template:**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let unit of units">{{ unit.daysRemaining | daysRemaining }}</li>
</ul>
```

Taking it one step further, we could extend the [I18nPluralPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/I18nPluralPipe) to pluralize the results within our custom pipe by extending the built in pipe and maybe check if the input is a valid number.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { I18nPluralPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({name: 'daysRemaining'})
export class DaysRemainingPipe extends I18nPluralPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(days: number): string {
    const safeDays = isNaN(days) ? 0 : days;

    const pluralMap = {
      '=0': '0 Days',
      '=1': '1 Day',
      'other': '# Days'
    };

    return super.transform(safeDays, pluralMap);
  }
}
```

Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ixoqff) in action.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: This is a much more effective solution than what I came up with. It works really well. Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your function is not returning anything. Check that the function is being called (put a `console.log` to see if actually is being executed).

However, maybe it would be better something like this.

```
<h2>{{ unit.daysRemaining + ' Days' }}</h2>
```

If that works, maybe the problem was a typo, or some scope visibility that you are missing there (is that template the template of the component?)